# Links from OWIN hosted WebApi to MVC and vice versa

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, owin, asp.net-web-api-routing

I want to generate url from mvc view to WebApi controller and from WebApi to MVC action. Normally these methods work perfectly:

```
// mvc to webapi
@Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Test" })

// webapi to mvc
Url.Link("Default", new { controller = "Home" }
```

After moving WebApi to OWIN host, these methods throw exceptions, as Mvc and WebApi do not see each other routes.

```
System.ArgumentException: A route named 'DefaultApi' could not be found in the route collection.
Parameter name: name
at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, String name, RouteValueDictionary values)
...
```

How can I generate these links, when WebApi is configured with OWIN host?

**Update:** my startup config:

```
public void ConfigureWebApi(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration { DependencyResolver = new StructureMapDependencyResolver(ObjectFactory.Container) };

    config.Filters.Add(new HandleHttpErrorAttribute());
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a known behavior with using Web API OWIN adapter in IIS hosted application. May I ask what your scenario is and why you are using Web API OWIN Adapter with IIS? I ask this because you could use OWIN middleware with Web API Webhosted application without using the Web API OWIN adpater..

Comment: @KiranChalla, I am not sure, what do you mean by "Owin Adapter". My application runs under IIS and I am using these owin related packages: `Owin, Microsoft.Owin`, `Microsoft.Owin.Security`, `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies`, `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`, `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin`. I started using Owin cookie authentication and tried to move WebApi to owin too. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: By Web API OWIN Adapter, I meant the package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin`...you should be able to use Owin cookie authentication without this package as far as i know...

Comment: Yes, Owin cookie authentication works perfectly without Owin WebApi. Problem is just with interoperability between mvc and owin-hosted WebApi. So I assume, currently there is no easy way to generate links from one system using other system's routes.